# How can one see how many strikes one's Global Entry card has received?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, borders, global-entry

When entering the US with Global Entry, one may receive a strike if the immigration/customs step [doesn't](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/169297/1810) [go](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/149561/1810)
[smoothly](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/169275/1810). How can one see how many strikes one's Global Entry card has received?

Comment: So what make you think that something like "strikes" exist in the first place ?

Comment: @Hilmar told so by CBP agents.