# Can't passengers of a car going through a Sentri lane bring their own luggage?

Tags: usa, luggage, borders, mexico, sentri

I read on https://expediteq.com/index.php?option=com_sppagebuilder&view=page&id=18 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220126232009/https://expediteq.com/index.php?option=com_sppagebuilder&view=page&id=18&jjj=1643239094049)):

> A car can only use the SENTRI lane if all passengers (including children and infants) have a valid SENTRI card and **passengers have nothing to declare at customs**.

Since the vehicle occupants [must](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/169275/1810) declare anything they bring to the US, does that mean passengers can't bring their own luggage when going through a Sentri lane?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133578/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-cant-passengers-of-a-car-going-thr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All passengers of a vehicle (including the driver) can bring their luggage through the SENTRI lane into the US.  ALL passengers must have a valid SENTRI card to use the lane, and if any non-SENTRI passengers are dropped off to walk through they must  take their luggage with them (non-SENTRI passengers cannot leave their luggage in the vehicle crossing through SENTRI).