# Am I allowed to videotape (dashcam) when entering the United States by car?

Tags: usa, driving, borders, regulations

I typically drive with a dashcam. Am I allowed to videotape (dashcam) when entering the United States by car, or must I stop my dashcam?

If I must stop my dashcam, what's the latest point when I need to stop the dashcam? (at the exact border, at the entrance of the queue, when the U.S. Customs and Border Protection facilities become visible, when the first US CBP agent becomes visible, when a US CBP agent asks me to stop it, etc.)

The [Welcome to the Trusted Traveler Program](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/169287/1810) brochure doesn't mention dashcams, except for the secondary ("All mobile/electronic devices must be turned off").

Comment: When there is a sign (as in customs/immigration in airport buildings)? Not an answer, I do not remember seeing such signs when passing the USA - Canada border.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks, same, I don't recall such no-camera signs when driving into the US.

Comment: I have been wondering this also, so have made a point of looking for signs the last 3 or 4 times I've driven across (from Mexico vida SENTRI lane) and have not seen any signs about photos/filming. It has been some time since I was in secondary but I believe there are signs in there, as well as within the CBP buildings, but I've seen none in the vehicle lanes outside of secondary.

Comment: You should probably specify where you're coming from - I expect enforcement will probably be a bit stricter at the Mexican border than the Canadian one.  And even then, may depend on which crossing you go to.

Comment: I think you should be fine keeping the dashcam on. That said, what the border patrol might say or do if they decide to pick on you is up in the air. Look at [this ACLU article on the 100 mile border zone](https://www.aclu.org/other/constitution-100-mile-border-zone). [The map that accompanies that article](https://www.aclu.org/sites/default/files/styles/scale_1200w_allow_upscale/public/field_feature_media_image/web18-100miborder-map-2400x1000px-v01.jpg?itok=rDq-QHhW) says it all: If you’re within 100 miles of a border within the U.S. the border patrol can override local, state or federal laws.

Comment: While travel related, I think this is probably more a Law.SE question than a travel one, as it relates to the legality of photography in general.

Comment: @PeterM we need https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/178179

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I am interested in both Canada->US and Mexico->US.

Answer (score 24):

A quick google search yields this: https://clearit.ca/canadian-customs-broker-blog/dashcam-recording-prohibited-u-s-ports-entry/ and this https://www.immigroup.com/topics/it-legal-use-dash-cam-border/ etc.

**Summary:** As is typical with the USBC, it's "we do whatever we want whenever we feel like it" or more politically correct: "the officer has the discretion to allow or disallow it". The legal underpinning to disallow it is this: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/41/102-74.420 and technically you would need permission or even written permission.

Enforcement seems to be all over the place, some people got significant amount of harassment for having a dash cam, but many other people report no problem whatsoever.

It's legal and allowed on the Canadian side.

Comment: I have a Tesla. It continuously records video from 6 cameras with no way to turn it off (that I know of), though it forgets what it saw after 10 minutes or so if I don't manually save the video permanently. I wonder when they'll require me to duct tape the camera lenses before approaching the border?

Comment: @Dennis also I wonder if they could revoke your global entry or similar card because of that.

Comment: @Dennis Stopping and duct taping the cameras - way to make yourself look *more* suspicious!

Comment: 1. Why is the cited 41 CFR § 102-74.420 relevant here? It's titled "What is the policy concerning photographs for **news, advertising or commercial** purposes?" A personal dashcam is none of those. The other websites you linked discuss this mainly in the context of commercial truckers. Is your argument that the law's title is not part of the law, so "non-commercial" in the text means *all* non-commercial, not just news and advertising? ...

Comment: ... 2. Please clarify whether you're answering OP's "am I allowed" in the sense of "do I risk being *told* to turn it off (and then everything's fine if I do)", "do I risk being *scrutinized more* by CBP", or "do I risk being *arrested and charged* with violating 41 CFR § 102-74.420". 3. You don't address OP's "what's the latest point" question. Presumably it would be "when the U.S. Customs and Border Protection facilities become visible", if you're going by the cited law that refers to "photographs **of...space occupied** by a tenant agency"?

Comment: @Dennis I've been visiting factories where all cameras you bring with you (e.g. on cell phones or laptops) are sealed with tamper proof stickers when entering the facilities, which are again checked and removed when leaving. Your suggestion is perhaps not so far away from reality as you may think.

Comment: " The legal underpinning to disallow it is this: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/41/102-74.420" That does not say anything about recording being prohibited, and in fact says the opposite. You'd have to make a "exception proves the rule" type argument, which would be rather flimsy.

Comment: @Dennis Would the Tesla even be possible to drive if you taped the cameras?

Comment: Those cameras, photonics and Lidar are essential to the functioning of the car's autopilot and driver warnings (e.g. lane drift when you are in manual drive mode).

Comment: @Dennis A lot of jurisdictions/manufactures will probably need to update how they handle these things because they are all over the place. For example: in Italy you have a right to record everything and everyone without consent **if** you are present and part of the events (you can even secretely record your sex encounters without telling the partner). However recording while you are absent without explicit signage is illegal *even in your own home*... so Tesla "sentinel" features are 100% illegal in Italy if you are away from your car, at some point this will go to court...

Comment: @nanoman: I thought my answer to all of those were clear: you won't know until you get there. In some cases nothing will happen. In other cases you may get told off or harassed. CBP isn't predictable or consistent.  I didn't see any examples of someone getting arrested, but that doesn't mean some extra grumpy CBP officer won't do it anyway. If you don't want to run the risk, just shut off the camera.

Answer (score 10):

**Probably**, but you may have to be prepared to litigate. Other answers here which purport to give a definite yes or a definite no are wrong.

The excellent *Papers, Please!* blog has [a detailed writeup](https://papersplease.org/wp/2022/04/19/photography-and-recording-at-us-border-crossings/) of a [2020 settlement](https://cbpabusestest2.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/2020-09-08-filed-stipulated-settlement.pdf) between the ACLU and the DHS, in which it was agreed that

> [t]he Department of Homeland Security and its components, including but not limited to U.S. Customs and Border Protection and Federal Protective Service, shall not prevent, impede, or otherwise interfere with the First Amendment rights of members of the public to make and retain photographs, video recordings, or other recordings of matters or events from a Publicly Accessible Area at any land port of entry in the United States. A Publicly Accessible Area is an outdoor area at a land port of entry where a member of the public is permitted to be regardless of whether they intend to cross the United States border.

*Papers, Please!* adds that

> We don’t mean to suggest that you don’t also have the right to record or livestream what happens to you as you cross the border. We think you do, but that hasn’t yet been litigated as extensively.

The ACLU [has a form to fill out](https://action.aclu.org/webform/help-us-hold-cbp-officials-accountable) if you believe your rights under this settlement have been violated.

Answer (score 6):

**Video recording outward from your dashboard or windshield, or rearward from your back window**

No problem at all in the US. You are recording scenes in which noone has any expectation of privacy, specifically a public street or highway.

**Audio recording the conversation that takes place inside your car?**

This gets iffy very quickly. A significant portion of US states make this illegal. Check the laws in each state you plan to travel in. Helpful search terms might be "one party consent" and "two party consent" to recording a conversation.

For this reason many dash cam makers that market their products in the US make it very quick and easy to start/stop the audio recording function. I myself own Garmin front and rear cams, and I can start or stop audio recording on both cams instantly with a single button click. I do audio when I'm alone in the car, audio-off when I have passengers.

**Rear facing camera mounted in the front?**

This situation I really don't know about. It's extremely widespread amongst taxi drivers, fleet drivers, and ride-sharing drivers, so I assume it's legal in at least some cases. But there might be some requirement to inform passengers with a sign or something.

**While crossing the border**

I think it's highly unlikely that any border officer in the US would take any issue with camera(s). If they do, then of course follow their commands at the time, whether it's to unplug the cam or completely pull it off your windshield. Then you can restart the camera(s) immediately after leaving their presence. Their professional opinion of the law is frequently incorrect and won't hold water in court. But it's better to defuse the situation long before a court appearance is necessary. If they can make a case that the camera(s) is obstructing the driver's view you will likely lose that case.

**Recording in restricted areas**

There are some places where video recording is prohibited. Military bases. Commercial ports. Maybe also international border crossings?

I'd like to think the border crossing officers are enlightened enough to realize that any car with self driving technology is probably recording extensively and that recording cannot be stopped. Teslas do for sure, and probably also many other high end high tech cars.

**Bottom line**

What I would do is pop that camera off the window and throw it in the cupholder just before approaching the border. Immediately after crossing, you can pull over and put the camera back up.

Comment: Thanks, good point, I should have written video+audio recording.

Comment: The links in Hilmar's answer state that truck drivers *are* being hassled over cameras at border crossings.

Comment: You're assuming a removable camera in most of the answer including the conclusion.  Many fairly ordinary cars have them built in these days

Comment: @chrish very true, as I mentioned with the Teslas. On the other hand, I think border officers would not notice or harass you about a built in camera! It's the obvious aftermarket one stuck to your windshield they might notice. So throw that one in your cupholder for a few minutes :)

Comment: @peterm those truckers should take my advice and throw their cameras in the cupholder for a few minutes at the border.

Answer (score 1):

There are some states that have laws against recording people, and these laws can depend on how close you are to the person being recorded, whether you have their permission, and whether audio is being recorded. Border agents are federal employees, so they probably won't be too concerned by state laws, but they theoretically could enforce them.

I don't think there's any federal law against recording. Even if there are, there is a strong constitutional case against such laws, as well as the state laws. But from a practical perspective, even if there is no statutory/constitutional basis for the prohibition, there's a lot that CBP can do to make your life more difficult. And while the constitution does apply to non-citizens, it's more difficult for them to assert it.

Comment: "there's a lot that CBP can do to make your life more difficult." -> can they revoke my Global Entry card?

Comment: The legal basis is https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/41/102-74.420  and it's certainly applied in Airports. Every immigration/customs area has signage that states that cell phone use or picture taking are prohibited. As usual, there is no consistency and enforcement is all over the place. There seem to be easing up: it's been a while since I saw someone get yelled at. However, I would not recommend trying to film a CBP officer in the booth.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt "can they revoke my Global Entry card?" - short answer is YES.  Longer answer is it probably depends on a lot of factors whether they're allowed to, but I've know people who have lost theirs for a lot less (including for things that are not against the rules).