# Am I allowed to videotape (dashcam) when entering Mexico from the US by car?

Tags: usa, driving, borders, mexico, regulations

I typically drive with a dashcam. Am I allowed to videotape (dashcam) when entering Mexico from the US by car, or must I stop my dashcam?

If I must stop my dashcam, what's the latest point when I need to stop the dashcam? (at the exact border, when the Mexican Customs and Border Protection facilities become visible, when the first Mexican agent becomes visible, when a Mexican agent asks me to stop it, etc.)

Comment: Umm...didn't you just ask [this same question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175141/am-i-allowed-to-videotape-dashcam-when-entering-the-united-states-by-car) a few days ago?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica This time it's about entering Mexico, not the US. Too many jurisdictions :(

Comment: Aha! Didn’t read carefully. Sorry.

Comment: Dupe voters - this is a different question to the other one asked recently.  A different country's rules/laws would apply here.

Comment: You stop it right after you pass the gum wall

Comment: @eps I'm still waiting for your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

As a mexican citizen crossed multiple times between the US and MX by car, let me share with you, that in my last experience a few months ago, I crossed to MX while my dashcam was turned on, I really did not take any care about that, no officials stopped me, even looked at me. However, I look like mexican, I had put my mexican hat, my car has mexican plates. If your car wears US plates, I think officials take more care about your required permissions than a dashcam turned on.

I think, that situation about dash cam could be more complicated if you are crossing from MX to the US, the officials are more careful.