Do Global Entry members need to declare personal purchases under the exemption?
If you're a Global Entry member with goods purchased purely for your own personal use (not biological or otherwise subject to special considerations - just everyday stuff like clothes, electronics, etc.), and they clearly fall within your personal exemption, do you have to declare anything when going through customs? Will they penalize you if you don't?
From what I have read online, some people say you will annoy the officers if you do, and some say you are required to declare everything even within your exemption. I don't get what the rules are.
P.S. I get that "always declare everything" is the safe advice, that's not the point. I'm asking what the actual rules are, not for mere guidance. A link to an authoritative page would go a long way.

Global entry memberships doesn't affect any requirements for customs declarations. You must declare all the items imported regardless of your membership status.
See the CBP webpage:

Also, anything you bring back that you did not have when you left the United States must be "declared."


While your answer is doubtless legally correct, nobody is going to declare everything to the CBP, nor are there any penalties for not doing as long as you're under the limits and not bringing anything restricted.

The question was about the rules. I usually say "I bought some gifts and snacks" and wait for follow ups. Since there's no longer a form, it's just a conversation with the guy at the booth.

For entries by land into the USA, one must declare every items even those acquired in the USA, see What am I supposed to declare when driving from Mexico to the United States, as a US lawful permanent resident? quoting an official document:

NOTHING TO DECLARE means you have nothing in your vehicle but yourself. It does NOT mean "nothing illegal" to declare!

That does seem to annoy some officers but they are the ones who annoyed me at the first place by sending me to secondary. I was send to secondary once when entering the USA from Mexico for failure to declare because at that time I was unaware of that rule. A US immigration officer told me during a secondary inspection when I was driving from Mexico to the United States that I should have declared items that I were already in my car when I entered Mexico from the US. When I asked him what specifically I should declare, he mentioned as example that I should have declared my clothes present in my car's trunk as well as my electronics. I was advised that my Global Entry privilege would be revoked if I do the mistake again.
And by everything I mean literally everything, i.e. everything single object. Typically they stop me after 5 or 10 items (it's done when discussing with the officer at the booth): "1 Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra, 1 iPhone 12 mini, 1 blue pen, 1 bottle of water, 2 t-shirts, 1 pair of shoes, 1 passport, 1 MSI laptop, etc."

I'm so confused what this means. Everyone travels with bags. Do you have to declare the bags? What about your toothbrush and passport? Surely they can't mean literally everything?

@user541686 Yes exactly, I would list the toothbrush, the bags themselves, the content of the bags and so on. But I don't recall any officer giving me the time to list more than 10 items. Typically they stop me after 5 or 10 items (it's done when discussing with the officer at the booth): "1 Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra, 1 iPhone 12 mini, 1 blue pen, 1 bottle of water, 2 t-shirts, 1 pair of shoes, 1 passport, 1 MSI laptop, etc." I was baffled too the first time I heard it at the secondary.

Wouldnt this take forever? Who even remembers exactly all the clothes they packed?

@user541686 I don't recall any officer giving me the time to list more than 10 items. I have a pretty good memory of what I have with me typically so I can play this dumb game, no problemo.

@user541686 and since the USA is an unsafe place (just like most other places), one sometimes can't even know what the car contains: How shall I proceed if my car may contain illegal drugs and drug paraphernalia before entering Canada by car from the US?. Traveling is a pain, I recommend just watching some YouTube travel videos if possible.

A US immigration officer told me during a secondary inspection when I was driving from Mexico to the United States that I should have declared items that I were already in my car when I entered Mexico from the US - this is absolutely incorrect. No matter what the CBP officer told you (and they're known to make things up), there's no such requirement.

@littleadv https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/169275/1810 quoting an official document:
"NOTHING TO DECLARE means you have nothing in your vehicle but yourself. It does NOT mean "nothing illegal" to declare!"

@FranckDernoncourt SENTRI is intended for Mexicans coming into the US. For them, everything they have with them is considered an import and must be declared. You, as a returning resident, only need to declare the stuff acquired abroad. See the link to the CBP guidance in my answer above.

@littleadv The official document from the US CBP that https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/169287/1810 quotes says "sentri/global entry"

@FranckDernoncourt right. Your card is "Global Entry", not "SENTRI". Not the same thing. The instructions were given to the person who received a SENTRI card. It's a slightly different program, but is run in combination with Global Entry (similarly to NEXUS on the Northern border). In any case, Global Entry is also available to non-Americans. But as a returning US resident you're only required to declare imports. That said, do whatever the CBP officers tell you. As I said, they make stuff up as they go and have a lot of power to make you very miserable even if they're absolutely in the wrong.
